# Installing VS-Code Extension without Internet Connectivity

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm seeking a method of installing extensions to VS-Code without having to be connected to the internet. The machine I'm running VS-Code on is restricted from connecting unfortunately. Are manual extensions/packages available for download?

The extension install utility within VS-Code only appears to work if connected to the internet, which allows online search/install/updates of extensions. I've tried looking for a 'manual' extension download within the VS-Code extensions page, and that requires an active and connected VS-Code session to be open. Conversely, when searching the extensions viewer within VS-Code there isn't an option to search 'locally' for extensions.

Comment: the phrasing of this question is weird. "_without having to be connected to the internet \[...\] Are manual extensions/packages available for **download**?_".

Comment: install from vsix dont need internet, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142812

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get the .vsix file from somewhere... so I am assuming you can download it on a machine that does have internet access and then transfer it to the machine that doesn't.  You can go to the [Visual Studio Code marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) which has all of the extensions you can find from within Visual Studio Code itself.  Find the extensions you want, and download them.  This will download the .vsix file(s).

[image: image showing how to download an extension from the marketplace website]

After that, you can then use the [command line to install the extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_command-line-extension-management). The command syntax is:

```
code --install-extension (<extension-id> | <extension-vsix-path>)
```

In your case, you would do:

```
code --install-extension C:\some\path\myextension.vsix
```